# IOS figure out shade of in grey keyboard buttons

Tags: ios

IOS default keyboard has the following buttons:

[image: ios keyboard buttons]

I am trying to make my own custom keyboard and I need to figure out the shade of grey/style (if they use something special to achieve that grey look) of these buttons.

I thought the RGB value was: (170,170,170)

but the UIColor `UIColor.init(red: 2/3, green: 2/3, blue: 2/3, alpha: 1)`
lends me a darker color that looks like this:

[image]

Am I possibly missing a transparency value and if so how can I figure it out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a color picker to figure it out.

It's (173, 180, 190).

Comment: Hmm.. I used a color picker too, I guess mine was inaccurate or I read it wrong?